# Does pass all [state, setState] to child component is an anti pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code like this

```
const ChildComponent = ({ products, setProducts }) => (
  <form>
    <input type="text" value={products.name} onChange={(e) => setProducts(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="submit" value="Finish" />
  </form>
)

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Test",
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Where i call API to get list product and set it to child component
  }, [])

  return <ChildComponent products={products} setProducts={setProducts} />
}
```

for some reason , i can ONLY update state of ParentComponent in ChildComponent. It's work but i think it's so weird, that look like i change props of child component everytime when i make a edit of input. Can any one tell me that is an anti pattern or not.Sorry about my bad English. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not anti-pattern to pass the state and state updater as props, but this does offload the responsibility to child components to update the state correctly and maintain the state invariant.

Comment: it's not an anti-pattern, but you should avoid passing all state to a child component, since, even a small change in state will trigger a re-render across all child components

Comment: @DrewReese do you recommend any alternative ? i think this solution make my code look so messy and hard to understand

Comment: What do you mean by "_for some reason , i can ONLY update state of ParentComponent in ChildComponent._"?

Comment: @SinanYaman i mean can't merge ChildComponent to ParentComponent. My real problem is not that short but the idea is the same! sorry for any confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an anti-pattern to pass the state object and state updater function as props, but this offloads the responsibility to update state correctly and maintain the state invariant to consuming components.

As you can see, your child component already messes up and changes the state shape/invariant from `Object` to `String`.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({ // <-- object
  id: 1,
  name: "Test",
});

... child

onChange={(e) => setProducts(e.target.value)} // <-- string value
```

On the subsequent render attempting to access `value={products.name}` in the child will fail as now `products` is a string.

I typically suggest declaring a handler function to do the state update and pass that instead.

In your snippet it seems the child component is more a "controlled input" meaning it's an `input` tag with a value and `onChange` handler. This is an example refactor I would do.

```
const ChildComponent = ({ value, onChange, onSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    <input type="submit" value="Finish" />
  </form>
)

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({
    id: 1,
    name: "Test",
  });

  const changeHandler = e => {
    setProducts(products => ({
      ...products,
      name: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // handle the form submission
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Where i call API to get list product and set it to child component
  }, []);

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      value={products}
      onChange={changeHandler}
      onSubmit={submitHandler}
    />
  );
}
```

This way the parent maintains control over both the state updates and how the form data is submitted. The child hasn't any idea what the value represents and it isn't trying to update anything in any way, but simply passing back out the events.